# How can I load UrlTIle in react native maps smoother when changing urlTemplate

Tags: expo, react-native-maps, openweathermap, weatherdata, url-template

Hello I am also facing this issue in react native maps expo. I am using slider, the slider shows the weather image on google maps with 1 hour step. but the issue I am facing is it takes 2-3 seconds to load new image on top of map when I change the slider (refreshing the UrlTile's key property). How can I make this transition smooth like apple weather app.

If anyone knows please help!!!

the weather layer image changes (by changing the key property of the UrlTile when slider moves) when I change the slider. but it takes 1-2 seconds to refresh the layer. How can I make this transition smooth like Apple Weather App